# stop changing numbers to date in excel

Tags: excel

When I type 12.5 in excel cell, it converts and returns 42867. I want to know is it possible to stop changing dotted numbers and leave them as typed and use SUM function to summarize numbers??
thanks in advance.

Comment: What region are you in?  Set the format of the cell to general before entering the number

Comment: Thank you . location was russian. I changed it english(USA) . and it works good . thanks too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's changing it to date. Go to format, and format the cell as a number or adjust your region if non U.S.